# How to view an object embedded with a document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

```
> db.orders.find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b78b933d62e262ddb055509"), "user_id" : "5b16d96a74be42566844e0b4", "game_id" : "5b11c56c6c71dc44976fba55", "seats" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5b78b933d62e262ddb05550a") }, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bb135638625d21c0883fe1d"), "user_id" : "5b16d96a74be42566844e0b4", "game_id" : "5b11c56c6c71dc44976fba61", "seats" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5bb135638625d21c0883fe1e") }, "__v" : 0 }
```

The above is the output of find command on the orders stored in my Mongo Instance.

seats is an array of objects embedded in the orders schema. How can I view and fetch the array stored in Object seats?

Answer (score 0):

`seats` is a cross-reference field which contains the ObjectIds to anther collection.

Are you using Mongoose? If so you need to use the [populate method](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate) to fill in the objects on `find` etc.